# Flexbox with a Scrolling Section that has a Sticky Toolbar

Tags: css, flexbox

I would like to create a flexbox layout that contains a scroll panel but inside each column there is a fixed toolbar that is always visible.

This is what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/TheFiddler/c7szbfhq/

```
.scroll-panel {
        display: flex;
        border: 2px dashed rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.35);
        overflow: scroll;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }

    .item {
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        overflow: hidden;
        flex: 1 0 auto;
    }

    .item-body {
        flex-grow: 1;
    }

    .item-sticky-footer {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        flex-basis: 60px;
        align-self: flex-end;
        bottom: 30px;
        height: 60px;
    }
```

There are two problems:

1) The item-sticky-footer does not stay at the bottom of the item column. It should always be at the bottom next to the wrapper row footer.

2) The item inside the scroll panel should not overflow. It should keep the max height of the layout content. If you change the height of an image to 3000px the footer gets pushed down. The scrollpanel is stretching when it should not.

I'm going for a carousel of items that each have a toolbar that stays inside the column and is always at the bottom.

After searching, I could not find a question that dealt with the sticky toolbar part.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` for `.item`. Then, you could also remove `align-self: flex-end` from `.item-sticky-footer` and so on.

```
.item {
    margin-right: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

2) In order to maintain the height of each item, you could set total viewport height (`100vh`) for `.scroll-panel` and subtract `header` and `footer` `heights` (you may know explicitly those heights), using calc: `max-height: calc(100vh - header height - footer height - extras).` So it will limit the height based on the window. Like this:

```
.scroll-panel {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px dashed rgba(114, 186, 94, 0.35);
    overflow: scroll;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    max-height: calc(100vh - 42px);
}
```

I hope this helps solve or give you a path to follow.

Comment: Not quite working, but I'll keep experimenting along these lines. Makes sense. Thanks

Comment: I can't get the vertical scrolling inside the scroll panel to work. If the content is taller than the height of the scroll panel, the vertical scroll bar is still not active. Any thoughts on that part?

Comment: You can set `max-height` (not using % in this case) for `.scroll-panel`. For example, using the same values as before: `max-height: calc(100vh - 42px);`. Then, if you test a higher `height` for item, for example, `height: 1000px`. you'll notice the`scroll` on panel.

Comment: You increased the `img`. I mentioned the `item`. In this case, you have to modify the item `overflow`.

Comment: I want the whole scroll panel to scroll together and to have the sticky toolbar always at the bottom of each column though. If I allow the item to scroll, it adds a scrollbar for every column. Also, don't I need a height so that the toolbar can be positioned at the bottom? I just want one vertical scroll for all of the columns together but the viewable area of each column to be fixed.